# The longest word that includes numbers that can be changed with letters in different languages

Tags: word, language

Let me take the English word **"stone"** as an example:

> Replacing the string "one" by the corresponding number "1"  allows me to write **stone** as **st1**

In Dutch, "stone" is translated to "steen" and "one" is translated to "een".

> Replacing the string "een" by the corresponding number "1"  allows me to write **steen** as **st1**

Now note that both in English and in Dutch this replacement process leads to the same string **"st1"**.

**Question:** What is the longest example of this type that you can come up with?

Notes:

- The translation of the numbers can't be the same in both languages.
- The score of the word is based on the amount of number/letters in the 
  word that contains the letters/numbers (not the words with letters only)
- The number cant refere to a number in a word like 100000ling (100000 would refer to a number)

---

Current highscore

```
points      word           user        Language
______________________________________________
4           all1           Gamow         nl-ger
3           st1            Sven b        nl-en
```

Comment: Can I use *centillion*? That's one with 600 zeros. Centillion translated to German is *Zentillion*, which can be written in its' numerical form as one with 600 zeros.

Answer (score 5):

German and english have a longer one:

> Freighter - Fr8er - Frachter

Answer (score 3):

Here is a repair to Ivo Beckers' first answer:

> 5ling

In Dutch: 5=**vijf**, and **vijf**ling=quintuplet.
In German: 5=**Fünf**, and **Fünf**ling=quintuplet.

---

Under the new rules:

> All1

In Dutch:  1=**een**, and All**een**= lonely
In German: 1=**ein**, and All**ein**= lonely

Comment: Is "vijflingsmama" a Dutch word? Is "Fünflingsmama" a German word?

Comment: not that i know

Comment: 10ling, 100ling, 1000ling, ....

Comment: I changed the rules a bit im sorry, else you could just write any number like  10000ling etc as @johannes pointed out

Comment: I don't know if it's in the rules but 1 in german would actually be "eins". The word "ein" is only used if you describe the amount of something. example: "one stone" -> "ein stein"